# Cassandra Ruby gem get columns

Tags: ruby, get, rubygems, cassandra

I access cassandra from the ruby gem. I want to retrive data from cassandra db by specifying which columns I want to. whenever I run this

> conn.get(:column_family, 'key1', [63,62])

I get the following error,

```
 TypeError: can't convert Array into String
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@spaghetti/gems/thrift-0.8.0/lib/thrift/transport/framed_transport.rb:84:in `write'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@spaghetti/gems/thrift-0.8.0/lib/thrift/protocol/binary_protocol.rb:112:in `write_string'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@spaghetti/gems/thrift-0.8.0/lib/thrift/client.rb:35:in `write'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@spaghetti/gems/thrift-0.8.0/lib/thrift/client.rb:35:in `send_message'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@spaghetti/bundler/gems/cassandra-7474449189f3/vendor/0.8/gen-rb/cassandra.rb:107:in `send_multiget_slice'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@spaghetti/bundler/gems/cassandra-7474449189f3/vendor/0.8/gen-rb/cassandra.rb:102:in `multiget_slice'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@spaghetti/bundler/gems/thrift_client-00893a3accc5/lib/thrift_client/abstract_thrift_client.rb:150:in `handled_proxy'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@spaghetti/bundler/gems/thrift_client-00893a3accc5/lib/thrift_client/abstract_thrift_client.rb:60:in `multiget_slice'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@spaghetti/bundler/gems/cassandra-7474449189f3/lib/cassandra/protocol.rb:64:in `_multiget'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@spaghetti/bundler/gems/cassandra-7474449189f3/lib/cassandra/cassandra.rb:619:in `multi_get'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@spaghetti/bundler/gems/cassandra-7474449189f3/lib/cassandra/cassandra.rb:592:in `get'
    from (irb):5:in `block in irb_binding'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@spaghetti/gems/connection_pool-0.1.0/lib/connection_pool.rb:41:in `with'
    from (irb):4
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

A python package 'pycassa' provides the option to specify which columns to be retrieved. How to do that in ruby??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently `.get()` and `.multi_get()` do not accept a list of column names. There is an [open issue for this on GitHub](https://github.com/twitter/cassandra/issues/136). As a work around you can use `.get_columns()` instead.

```
conn.get_columns(:column_family, 'key1', [63,62])
```

This returns an array of values in the same order as you specified for your column names. Alternatively you could use the `cassandra-cql` gem:

```
handle.execute("select 63,62 from column_family where KEY = 'key1'").fetch
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my reading of the gem it is your `[63,62]` that is throwing off the gem. The syntax for the third argument is expecting a string for sub-column.

From the tests in the [source code](https://github.com/twitter/cassandra/blob/master/test/cassandra_test.rb):

```
@twitter.get(:Users, key, 'user') #@twitter == your conn
```

There is also `@twitter.multi_get(:Users, [key + '1', key + '2', 'bogus'])` that allows you to get many items at once.